# Why air cannot be used as a cooling medium in CO2 refrigeration system?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, heat-transfer, refrigeration

Can anyone please explain the reason for above question?

Comment: Requirement is that the coolant be significantly cooler than what you wish to cool.  This difference drives heat to the coolant.  What form does this air take at that temperature and high enough pressure to pump it? Probably not entirely gas anymore...

Comment: The question is probably asked to find out what the person who is asked the question knows about the gases, cooling of the system and constraints.

Comment: Certainly could use clarification.  Could be a translation/language issue where the word "reason" in the context of a "why" question should be interpreted as "answer"

Answer (score 0):

Refrigerant systems that uses boiling and condensing (like CO2 and regular Freon systems) require a single refrigerant because otherwise you have multiple boiling/consensing temperatures/pressures.  Air is mostly nitrogen and oxygen, which have different boiling points.